# How to connect different pages to homepage in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Here I have two pages one is **nav.dart and function name is Nav() (navigation Bar) ** and another is card.dart Function name id DashboardCard()

How to connect these two function to my home page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:enkindle/nav.dart';
import 'package:enkindle/card.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child:
      
    );
  }
}
'''
```

Comment: You might be looking for [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you require is to Navigate.push() action when a button is pressed. Use something like this:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Open route'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
            );
          },
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Where SecondRoute() is your second route you want to navigate to.

And to come back to previous page, use the code below in a container or wherever you want:

```
     child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
```